# Packaged jar from scala code not executing properly

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to figure out, how I can execute Scala Code as an executable jar file.
So I've loaded a Hello World Script which just hast this code

```scala
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello, World!")
}
```

This is located within `src\main\scala\Main.scala`.
Now im running `sbt package` to create a jar file.
However, I'm not able to run this file, it just won't do anything.
Also, by going in the directory and running it via `java -jar HelloWorld.jar` is not working and I'm just getting the Error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
```

However I have no clue why this happens and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0

I think you do not have Scala runtime libraries on the classpath.

You either need to provide a complete class-path with all libraries, or to use [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin to create a [fat JAR](https://imagej.net/develop/uber-jars).